# What fish / insects will become unavailable after the end of March?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

While some species of fauna in Animal Crossing: New Leaf are available all the time (curse you, wasp!), other species are time-sensitive, only appearing during certain months.

Given that New Horizons came out on the 20th, the end of the month is already nigh, and I'd like to prioritize catching any critters that won't be available come April! Does anyone have a list of soon-to-be-vanished endemic life?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found [this list](https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/3/25/21194292/march-bugs-fish-insects-critterpedia-leaving-last-chance) of Fish and bugs leaving before the end of March, courtesy of Polygon.

Two locations which may not be immediately obvious are **River (Clifftop)** and **River (Mouth)**. Based on my experience with past games in the series, along with some reading along, Clifftop appears to be any river **not on the lowest level**, and River (Mouth) is the area where the river connects with the sea.

### Northen Hemisphere

There are **7** fish / insects that won't be available starting in April in the Northern Hemisphere.

[image]

### Southern Hemisphere

There are **39** fish / insects that won't be available starting in April in the Southern Hemisphere.

[image]